# C# - command line application calls

Tags: c#

I have done plenty of C# shell command calls, apps, batch files etc. The other day I was asked if it would be a problem if an executable that I currently run from my web site app, would move to another server on our intranet. 
In other words the web site app and the executable that I am running through Process.Start(...) are located on the same box currently - all good there. Now there is a wish to separate the two on two different servers.

I done a few futile attempts to execute an app (located on server B) from server A (where the web site resides).
Is there a way that I have not run cross yet to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why were the attempts futile?  What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Use sockets. or poke it via http.

Comment: the standard way of communicating to another process on a remote machine is using WCF or any other ipc mechanism

Answer (score 4):

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) is one way with minimal coding.  Using `System.Diagnostic.Process`, you can call this command:

```
psexec \\ServerB (path)\myapp.exe arg0 arg1 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the processes of server A by running an application on server B, you would need an application running on server B that would get controlled remotely somehow.

As an example, let's say server A runs unix, so you could write a application that would connect to server A using ssh, authenticate and then control the processes and whatnot like you do in a shell. If server A does not allow ssh connection, you could write your own application that would be running on server A listening to some connection and commands that would come from an application in server B.

It's quite hard to understand what are your current settings and why would you even want to switch the application from server A to server B, so a little more information would wield you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Austin's PSExec approach is probably the easiest approach to executing an EXE on a remote machine, but you may want to consider a potentially more robust solution:

You could modify your command-line app to run as a service and to respond to requests for work and/or data via a WCF (binaryXML/TCP or XML/HTTP) call.